# Not able to pull from Mongo db using Morphia - No usable constructor

Tags: java, mongodb, shiro, morphia

So i'm trying to save the password in sha265 into mongo db and use `Apache Shiro` framework in order to authorize the user login, while trying to pull from the DB i'm getting morphia run time exception, here is the code :

User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable{

        @Id 
        private ObjectId id; 
        private String name; 
        private String password;
        private SimpleByteSource passwordSalt;

        @Embedded 
        private TenantId tenantId; 
        private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();



        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "User [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", password="
                    + password + ", passwordSalt=" + passwordSalt
                    + ", tenantId=" + tenantId + ", roles=" + roles + "]";
        }
        public SimpleByteSource getPasswordSalt() {
            return passwordSalt;
        }
        public void setPasswordSalt(SimpleByteSource passwordSalt) {
            this.passwordSalt = passwordSalt;
        }
        public ObjectId getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(ObjectId id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
        public TenantId getTenantId() {
            return tenantId;
        }
        public void setTenantId(TenantId tenantId) {
            this.tenantId = tenantId;
        }
        public Set<String> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }
        public void setRoles(Set<String> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        } 

}
```

test class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient m_mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1",27017);
        Morphia  m_morphiaMongoDB = new Morphia();
        Datastore ds = m_morphiaMongoDB.createDatastore(m_mongoClient, "test");

        RandomNumberGenerator rng = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator();
        SimpleByteSource salt = (SimpleByteSource) rng.nextBytes();
        String hashedPasswordBase64 = new Sha256Hash("1234", salt, 1024).toBase64();
        User temp = new User();

        temp.setName("Myname");
        //temp.setPassword("1234");
        temp.setPassword(hashedPasswordBase64);
        temp.setPasswordSalt(salt);

        ds.save(temp);

        User user = ds.find(User.class).field("name").equal("Myname").get();
        System.out.println(user);

    }
```

I'm using `Shiro` and Morphia, this is what i'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: No usable constructor for org.apache.shiro.util.SimpleByteSource
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:171)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:617)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:592)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:306)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:79)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:65)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:60)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.get(QueryImpl.java:421)
    at com.roi.shiro.realm.temp.main(temp.java:31)
Caused by: org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappingException: No usable constructor for org.apache.shiro.util.SimpleByteSource
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getNoArgsConstructor(DefaultCreator.java:140)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInst(DefaultCreator.java:109)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:27)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:35)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.createInstance(DefaultCreator.java:45)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:161)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.shiro.util.SimpleByteSource.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3074)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.DefaultCreator.getNoArgsConstructor(DefaultCreator.java:136)
    ... 13 more
```

SimpleByteSource has the following constructor:

```
 public SimpleByteSource(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't save that object with Morphia.  Morphia needs a zero-arg constructor to create the class before populating its fields.  You'll need to save that byte[] on a field in your User class instead.

Comment: I just had another thought.  You could probably write a converter for that field that'd take the `byte[]`, create the `SimpleByteSource`, and return that.  That would also work and would preserve your object model.

Comment: fwiw, Morphia 2.2 supports using constructors as long as every field is present in that constructor.